# How to parse a JSON document into a database

Tags: java, mysql, json, parsing

I have a JSON document with information on a product, and I want to parse the JSON document and put it into a database.

An Example JSON document:

```
{
"itemize": {
   "pr": "2583",

       "n": "Chocolate donut",

       "yst": "A beautiful, premium chocolate donut"

       "wh": 2.99

}
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

public class q1 {
public static void addProduct()
{
    JSONParser parser=new JSONParser();

    try{

        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("c.\\itemize.json"));
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

        String pr = (String) jsonObject.get("Pr");
        //Put pr into database

        String n = (String) jsonObject.get("n");
        //Put n into database

        String yst = (String) jsonObject.get("yst");
        //Put yst into database

        String wh = (String) jsonObject.get("wh");
        //Put wh into database

    }
}
}
```

The database is in MySQL and has all these columns already. I just need to replace the commented lines in the java code with lines that will put the string into the database. This is what the database looks like:

```
Pr VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
n VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
yst VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
wh VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
Primary Key (Product_ID));
```

Comment: Use a `java.sql.PreparedStatement`.

Comment: To make code useful, you do need to add 2nd record, so some code get all tags make difference for you to understand, may change the way you coding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Java interface for accessing databases is Java Database Connectivity (JDBC). Using JDBC you can create a connection to the database, issue database queries and updates and receive the results. try the following code

```
  private Connection connect = null;
  PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

 public int save() throws Exception {
   int status = 0;  
    try {
      // Load the MySQL driver, each DB has its own driver
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

      // DB connection setup 
      connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://dbhost/database?" + "user=sqluser&password=sqluserpw");

      // PreparedStatements 
      preparedStatement = connect
          .prepareStatement("insert into  Table_Name values (?, ?, ?, ? )");

      Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("c.\\itemize.json"));
      JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

      String pr = (String) jsonObject.get("Pr");
      // Parameters start with 1
      preparedStatement.setString(1, pr);

      String n = (String) itemize.get("n");
      preparedStatement.setString(2, n);

      String yst = (String) jsonObject.get("yst");
      preparedStatement.setString(3, yst);

      String wh = (String) itemize.get("wh");
      preparedStatement.setString(4, wh);

      status = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw e;
    } finally {
      try {
          if (connect != null) {
             connect.close();
           }

         } catch (Exception e) {

         }
    }
    return status;
  }
```

Comment: What is 1,2, 3,4.. Is that some kind of index or Column attributes ?

Comment: Its placeholder (? in insert prepared statement) index. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Answer (score 2):

Do like this.

```
    Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("c.\\itemize.json"));
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject ) obj;
    JSONObject   itemize = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("itemize");
    String pr = (String) itemize.get("Pr");
    String n = (String) itemize.get("n");
    String yst = (String) itemize.get("yst");
    String wh = (String) itemize.get("wh");
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all I recommend you to use qualified names for your variables both in your code and database.
   after all your code, use these lines to create inserts

```
  //use DriverManager to getConnection for your mySQL
    conObj = getConnection();
    String preQueryStatement = "INSERT  INTO  <TABLENAME>  VALUES  (?,?,?,?)";
    pStmnt = conObj.prepareStatement(preQueryStatement);
    pStmnt.setString(1, Pr );
    pStmnt.setString(2, n);
    pStmnt.setString(3, yst );
    pStmnt.setInt(4, wh );
 // execute insert SQL stetement
    preparedStatement .executeUpdate();
```